# Могут ли несколько человек выгружать свои проекты на Github?

Tags: git, github

Мое учебное задание - чтобы каждый студент группы свои работы загружал в один репозиторий.

Мне нужно реализовать репозиторий github в который несколько человек будут загружать свои проекты. Нужно чтобы была одна ветка, в которую люди загружают проекты.

Я пытался это реализовать, я загрузил один файл в репозиторий в ветку master, потом дал доступ другому человеку к репозиторию и он в эту же ветку загрузил свой проект, но при этом мой файл удалился.

Во время выгрузки файла, появилась такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли это сделать как нибудь, чтобы все файлы других людей оставались нетронутыми?

Comment: зачем выгружать всем в один репозитарий, если есть возможность делать пулл реквесты?

Comment: это извращение загружать с одного аккаунта в один проект в одну ветку разные проекты.

Comment: @xmikex Это учебное задание мое) Чтобы каждый студент группы свои работы выгружали в один репозиторий...

Comment: @Alexandr не с одного аккаунта, с разных аккаунов файлы в один репозиторий

Comment: Ответ - могут, конечно. Однако, чтобы разобраться почему ваш файл удалился - надо больше конкретики - что делали, какие варнинги видели, итп итд

Comment: @Kromster я прикрепил скришнот ошибки, которая возникла при выгрузке файла вторым человеком

Comment: Вам удалось прочесть текст ошибки, понять его и попробовать то что в нем предложено?

Comment: надо стянуть изменения перед тем как пушить, видимо кто то запушил быстрее

Comment: А текст в консоли для дурачков?

Comment: В конце то концов, почитайте официальную книжку!:
https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2

Comment: Форки? Не, ен слышали...

Answer (score 2):

1. Ваше учебное задание, *видимо*, предполагало формулировку "научиться совместно работать с проектами в git". Или - "научиться совместно работать с проектами в github". Для начала - обратите внимание, что это *не одно и то же*.
2. В гитхаб можно без ограничений *совместно* работать с публичными проектами, и с некотрыми ограничениями по числу участников - с приватными проектами. При этом у каждого участника должен быть свой экаунт на гитхабе.
3. В ошибке, которую Вы привели, есть волшебные слова "forced update", которые на русский перводятся как "перезаписать всё, что было в репозитории, к чёртовой матери, и гори оно всё огнём!". Применять такую бескомпромиссную политику следует осмотрительно и только если она действительно нужна.
4. В комментариях Вам правильно написали, что при совместной работе лучше не делать коммиты, а присылать пул - реквесты. Вообще, по гиту и гитхабу есть множество хороших учебных пособий, начиная от [Pro GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2), и заканчивая видео на ютьюбе, котрые Вы найдёте  без моей помощи.
5. Если быть *очень* кратким, то план должен быть такой: как создавать репозиторий? как клонировать его к себе? как добавлять файлы для коммита? как коммитить? как пушить? Что такое ветки и как устроена схема работы с несколькими верками проекта? как создавать пулл-реквестыи принимать их? Если с этим *немного* поразбираться, потратив на каждый из этих вопросов хотя бы по 15 мин - всё станет гораздо понятнее.

ТОгда, если вопросы еще будут, Вы можете дополнить Ваш вопрос, отредактировав его.